# if(!buydat.empty()) validation fails (always true)

Tags: c++, validation, vector

I have an 'if validation' that is always true, even when I delete the inbound data it is receiving to ensure it is empty, I still reach my cout statement when it should not.

code:

```
void buymngr(){
        vector<std::string> buydat;
        vector<std::string> markdat;
        vector<std::string> pricedat;
        buydat = getmyData();
        if(!buydat.empty()){

                cout << "You 'do' have buy string match data!" << endl;
        }
```

It calls the function getmyData which is responsible for obtaining the data

getmyData:

```
vector<string> getmyData()
{
        FILE *mydfp = popen("php getMyorders.php", "r");
        if (mydfp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        char mydbuff[BUFSIZ];
        vector<string> vrecords;
        while(fgets(mydbuff, sizeof(mydbuff), mydfp) != NULL){
                size_t n = strlen(mydbuff);
                //clean '\0' from fgets
                if (n && mydbuff[n - 1] == '\n') mydbuff[n - 1] = '\0';
                if (mydbuff[0] != '\0') vrecords.push_back(mydbuff);
        }
        cout << "I got my own data" << endl;
        return vrecords;
}
```

When the code is legitimately 'true', it runs fine and performs all functions as normal.
But when made false, it still validates true and then segment faults (gdb does not point to a specific line but the error truly appear to be trying to process valid data which really is not there).

Comment: What are you using to erase the `vector`?  Have you tried [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)?

Comment: I am not trying to erase the vector.

Comment: You said your test case of `!buydat.empty()` on an empty vector was still returning true after you cleared the vector to test it, unless I am misunderstanding?  There may be an issue with your method to erase all the vector data, because I am relatively sure it's not an issue with `empty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement checks that `b < buydat.size()`.  You could index beyond the end of the vector with this statement:

```
if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ){
    pricedat.push_back(buydat[b+1]);
}
```

On edit: what I meant by "You could index..." was "You could BE INDEXING...".
It was an observation, not a suggestion:  You are adding `buydat[b+1]` to the `pricedat` vector.  If `(b == (buydat.size()-1))` in your test, you will `push_back(buydat[buydat.size()]` - not valid.  Your posted code does not have any test to make sure that `buydat.size()` is less than `b+N` (whatever `N` is - I'm guessing 7 based on your `for` loop)

Comment: if I do that, then I end up with a couple of functions inside that for() loop //because of the rest of the code. The live code is a few hundred lines more. If possible, I would like to have the validation prior. But thank dearly for your idea.

Comment: I am not concerned with buda.size. That function does what it is supposed to do, but it is only supposed to do it with valid data. my failure is at -> if(!buydat[0].empty()){, it is always true (before buydat.size).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, so following up as answer:
Then your problem is in `getMyData()`.  Consider:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::vector<std::string> getmyData()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vrecords;
    vrecords.push_back("anything.");
    vrecords.push_back("anything 2.");
    // push some more data here so the result -looks- like
    // whatever you expect the output of your PHP to be.

    // also, your original version of this function never closes mydfp

    return vrecords;
}

void buymngr(){
    std::vector<std::string> buydat;
    std::vector<std::string> markdat;
    std::vector<std::string> pricedat;
    buydat = getmyData();
    if(!buydat.empty()){
        std::cout << "You 'do' have buy string match data!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    buymngr();
    return 0;
}
```

Check the output of `getMyorders.php` - if the output is wrong, well, there're your problem.  If not, post the output of `getMyOrders.php`.

Comment: This code works correctly. here is the raw data  https://bpaste.net/show/106244fa62b8